# ggplot histogram adjusting the limits

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to make a basic histogram with ggplot, showing the distribution of students who chose one of four instructor profiles as their **first** preference for a particular course. So in other words, students read: "When taking course "X", rank which instructor type (4 different professor types/profiles) that you would prefer teach the class." As a first jab, I wanted to make a histogram showing the distribution of students' first instructor preference. The problem I am running into, however, is that no one chose instructor number 4. I think it is visually important to show that no one chose 4. But in geom_histogram, it doesn't include 1, 2, 3, and 4 as integers on the X-axis. Here is the code I am using:

```
ggplot(data = Preference, aes(Preference$First_FTF)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.25, boundary = 0, close = "left") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:4)
```

Any suggestions? It'd be nice to have 1, 2, 3, and 4 on the X-axis.

[image]

Comment: You can use the limits argument in scale_x_continuous. Also, don't use the $ notation inside aes

Comment: A side note: since you have an inherently categorical variable on the x-axis ("instructor type") you should probably use a discrete scale rather than a continuous one.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the range of an axis by using the limits argument in scale_x_continuous or scale_y_continuous. In your example:

```
ggplot(data = Preference, aes(Preference$First_FTF)) +
      geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.25, boundary = 0, close = "left") + 
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1,4))
```

Comment: How is this different from @RichardTelford's answer in the comment section?

Comment: This worked! Thank you!

Comment: @MauritsEvers I hadn't read the comment. My bad :/

Comment: @MauritsEvers I'd say it's different in the sense that it's an answer, not a comment. Answers-as-comments without also closing the question are problematic because they leave questions as "open" even though they really have been answered.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila While I generally agree with you on the answers-as-comments notion, courtesy and SO etiquette would've supported a request for RichardTelford to turn his comment into an answer, rather than re-posting his comment-answer as an independent answer to "claim the points".

Answer (score 0):

`xlim` and `ylim` can be used on **ggplot** to apply limits on the chart area -

```
ggplot(data = Preference, aes(Preference$First_FTF)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.25, boundary = 0, close = "left") + 
  xlim(1, 4)
```